# Collect stream into a HashMap with Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I have a HashMap which I need to filter using some function:

```
HashMap<Set<Integer>, Double> container
Map.Entry<Set<Integer>, Double> map = container.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(k -> k.getKey().size() == size)
```

For the size = 2 the following should be valid:

```
containerBeforeFilter = {1,2,3} -> 1.5, {1,2} -> 1.3
containerAfterFilter = {1,2} -> 1.3
```

After I applied the function in the filter, I want to collect results again into a HashMap. However, when I try to apply the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903137/java8-hashmapx-y-to-hashmapx-z-using-stream-map-reduce-collector), I'm getting illegal statements.

So the following statement, applied after the filter, is illegal:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap((entry) -> entry.getKey(), (entry) -> entry.getValue()));
```

What would be the proper way of collecting unchanged map values, where the only criteria is satisfying some key?

**UPDATE**

The mistake in the above code is the declared type of the variable `map`. It should have been `Map` rather than `Map.Entry`.

So the now functional code is:

```
Map<Set<Integer>, Double> map = container.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(k -> k.getKey().size() == size)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Can you post which Java version you're using? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It is the latest JDK 8u65

Comment: I'm also using latest JDK and this doesn't work for you: `Map<Set<Integer>, Double> collect = container.entrySet().stream().filter(k -> k.getKey().size() == size).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));`

Comment: Ok, I found the problem thanks to you @Flown! The problem was the type of the map variable! It must be Map not Map.Entry. Very silly mistake. Now the Collectors work as well! Thanks!

Comment: @wero Possibly. NetBeans 8.0.2 doesn't complain and it builds successfully.

Comment: You might simplify by using `container.keySet()`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seems that `Collectors.toMap` does not pick up the type arguments of `stream.collect` in your example and only returns a `Map<Object,Object>`.

As a workaround you can create the result map yourself and in the last stream step add the filtered entries to the result map:

```
Map<Set<Integer>, Double> result = new HashMap<>();
container.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().size() == size)
    .forEach(entry -> result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Yes, this approach works well! Although, it is weird why the other approach fails. Thanks!

Comment: Collectors.toMap has bug. Its not accepting duplicate values

Comment: If you have a chance of duplicate keys, see the other answer...in this case you don't because you know the input started as a Hash...

Answer (score 55):

If your ending map has a chance of "duplicate keys", there is a better solution using

```
toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                            Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                            BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                            Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

You could use it like this:

```
HashMap<Set<Integer>, Double> map = container.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(k -> k.getKey().size() == size)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (prev, next) -> next, HashMap::new));
```

Then as duplicate keys are added, it will use the latest instead of [throwing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231743/32453).  The last parameter is optional.

If you want to keep duplicate keys into a list, then use `Collectors.groupingBy` instead.

Comment: thank you , can you please explain , what are you doing here ,.... Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (prev, next) -> next, HashMap::new) ??

Comment: @Shyam, you can find explanation at Javadocs:
`Map.Entry::getKey` equals to `entry -> entry.getKey()` - **keyMapper** mapping function to produce keys
`Map.Entry::getValue` equals to `entry -> entry.getValue()` - **valueMapper** mapping function to produce values
`(prev, next) -> next` - **mergeFunction** merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)
`HashMap::new` equals to `() -> new HashMap<>()` - **mapSupplier** function which returns a new, empty Map into which the results will be inserted

Comment: thank you so much , can you elaborate a bit on """ (prev, next) -> next - mergeFunction merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction) """  where are you mentioning here to merge ?

Comment: here """ .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (prev, next) -> next, HashMap::new)); """    collect returns HashMap ?   HashMap takes  (K &V) right , why are passing 4 arguments here ... how it works ? what is key here and what is val for returning hashmap ?