# Java8: Map<X, Y> to Map<X, Z> using RxJava

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, rx-java

I know how to transform `Map<X, Y>` to `Map<X, Z>` using stream and it there was also a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903137/java8-hashmapx-y-to-hashmapx-z-using-stream-map-reduce-collector) about this.

**But I want to learn how do it using RxJava.**

And to be more specific:

```
//Input: 
Map<String,String> in; // map from key to a string number, for example: "10"

//transform: in -> out

//Output:
Map<String,Integer> out; //map from the same key to Integer.parseInt(val) (invariant: val is a string number)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with RxJava? If you have all data already available, any traditional method should work.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use RxJava, and I encountered this problem and wondered if it is possible to solve it using RxJava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Observable.toMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toMap(rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Func1)).

I think this is a minimal example:

```
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>() {

    {
        put("1", "1");
        put("2", "2");
    }
};
Map<String, Integer> res = Observable.from(test.entrySet()).toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue())).toBlocking().first();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Dávid Karnok is right in a sense that it is not particularly useful case for RxJava if your only goal is to convert a single map. 
It might make more sense if you have Observable of (multiple) maps.

Then I would recommend to use a convenience of Guava transformers: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function)

```
Map<String,String> source1 = ...
Map<String,String> source2 = ...

Observable.just(source1, source2)
    .map(map->Maps.transformValues(map, v->Integer.parseInt(v)));
```

One nice thing about Guava's map value transformer is that it does not recreate map data structure, but instead creates a transformed view which maps values lazily (on the fly).

If you do not want to depend on Guava, you can just trivially implement `Func1<Map<String,String>,Map<String,Integer>>` yourself.