# using java 8 to group list of object by object attribute of type list: JAVA

Tags: java, grouping

I have an Object like

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private List<String> brands_ids;
}
```

and I have a list of User objects like:
example data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "brands_ids": [
      10,
      20,
      30
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "brands_ids": [
      10,
      50
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "brands_ids": [
      10,
      80
    ]
  }
]
```

My Question is, How to Group this list to know in which objects the brand id appears, for example brand id=10 appears in all three objects, the brand id=30 only in one object

a result of a map with key=brand id and value = count would solve my issue
something like this:  {10:3},{20:1},{30,1},{50,1},{80,1}

Comment: I'm confused. Do you just want to count them or do you want a way to ask what id's have which brands? If you have tried to group them from iterating over a list of User objects, please share the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903137/java8-hashmapx-y-to-hashmapx-z-using-stream-map-reduce-collector/25903190)

This code fragment create 3 users, like in your example.

```
    var users = Arrays.asList(
            new User("1", Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30")),
            new User("2", Arrays.asList("10", "50")),
            new User("3", Arrays.asList("10", "80")));

    Map<String, Long> result = users
            .stream()
            .flatMap(user -> user.getBrand_ids().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(result);
    // Result is: {80=1, 50=1, 30=1, 20=1, 10=3}
```

Comment: If you use java 8, just change FROM: 'var users' TO 'List<User> users'

Comment: hi @vas, i wonder how to make result as list ?