# Is it possible to add just the values of a HashMap into another HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Hashmap `HashMap <Integer, Integer> map` and I want to change the `keyset()` type to a BinaryTreeNode, which was declared beforehand already, instead of an int, which I am able to do. However, I was wondering how could I add the appropriate `map.values()` in the same order as it was in my original HashMap `map`

Here is my code

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < map.keySet().size(); i++){
      BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(i);
      l.put(node, map.values());
    }
```

What changes to my code should I make to ensure that this would compile and do as I want it o?

Comment: I think you almost have it, but you're trying to put the entire old map into each key of the new map - instead you should only add what you get by looking up that particular key.

Comment: Since a HashMap has no defined order asking if you can add anything to it "in the same order" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also it would be cleaner to iterate over the keys and values instead of using a for loop. In general for looping over indices like that is a discouraged practice in modern programming.

Comment: @EdwardPeters so I could just say l.put(BinaryTreeNode, map.keyset())?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS what I meant was like add the values for every key correctly despite the change in data type. I'm not sure if changing the data type would change the value or not

Comment: ` l.put(BinaryTreeNode, map.keyset())` doesn't make any sense - give me a sec, I'll write up a more thorough answer.

Comment: @Droid Then why not just Iterate over the entrySet? A simple `for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())` loop and then you can get the key and value via `entry.getKey();` and `entry.getValue();` (And do something like `l.put(new BinaryTreeNode(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());` to fill your new map)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain insertion order, you would need to create LinkedHashMap. HashMap doesn't gaurantee order.

```
  LinkedHashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

It works like a HashMap but preserves order.

Answer (score 0):

First, some notes on what you have:

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < map.keySet().size(); i++){
      BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(i);
      l.put(node, map.values());
    }
```

`BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(i);`
Is probably wrong - `i` is just the index, which doesn't really mean anything as HashMaps aren't ordered in any defined way.

`l.put(node, map.values());` Is also wrong - here the value you're inserting is the entire original map.

You could save your current code by converting the keyset to an indexible structure (like a list - it's currently a set), and then grabbing the key at that index, converting it to a `BinaryTreeNode`, looking up the value associated with they key in the old map, and then adding both.

I probably have some syntax errors (I'm not in front of a compiler), but that would look something like:

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    List keyList = ArrayList(map.keySet());
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyList().size(); i++){
      Integer key = keyList.get(i);
      BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(key);
      l.put(node, map.get(key));
    }
```

But personally I think that's a really bad way to go about it.

What you probably want to do is instead iterate over the entry set:

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
      BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(entry.getKey());
      l.put(node, entry.getValue());
    }
```

This latter method is cleaner because it isn't manually mucking about with indices, which is generally a poor practice. Simpler still is to use a higher-order function, as in:

```
public static BinaryTreeNode parentMapToTree(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    HashMap<BinaryTreeNode, Integer> l = new HashMap<>();
    map.forEach((key,value) -> l.put(new BinaryTreeNode(key), value));
    }
```

That last one is skipping manual iteration altogether, and just passing the structure a function to run on each of its entries.

You can actually do one better, and skip initializing the new hashmap at all by using a `map` function (distinct from a HashMap data structure - totally different meaning.) See [Java8: HashMap<X, Y> to HashMap<X, Z> using Stream / Map-Reduce / Collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903137/java8-hashmapx-y-to-hashmapx-z-using-stream-map-reduce-collector) for more on that.

Comment: Thanks, editted those in.